# Transformer output too high. I'm sure this should be 12V but it is outputting 25V

Tags: transformer, fault

I have a faulty circuit board taken from a garage opening unit powered by a transformer.  I have 25V from each of the transformer terminals (4 of them), 50V on the 24V relays and all terminals have voltage, they're not switching. Remote does nothing and the board is not working at all.

To me it seems the voltage is too high. Could it be a faulty transformer? It surely should be outputting 12V on each winding instead of 25V. One winding goes straight to a 12V maximum lamp but it's sending 25V.

The relays which are 24VDC (OMRON GDRL-2-E) are getting 50V across all terminals except the coil which is getting 30V.

Something has a slight buzz too, not sure if it's the board or transformer

Pictures here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iTxc.jpg

Comment: What’s feeding it? Any 110/220 V selector/switch by any chance? Please draw a block diagram from power input and everything between it and your board.

Comment: Just a 230v transformer that plugs into the wall socket

Comment: What’s the open circuit voltage on it?

Comment: Shortage between primary winds may cause it. If you can measure primary wind current without load and it looks too high, that's it.

Comment: Ok so I've just checked it all unconnected. Windings 1-2 = 13V. 2-3 = 12.1V. 3-4 = 12.7V. But 1-3 =25V. 1-4 = 38V. 2-4 = 25V. Picture for reference: https://imgur.com/a/SStpC8C  Does that sound normal? If so what would be causing the high voltage once its connected to the board?

Comment: I've also checked it with my load lamp and the bulbs are dim so I don't think there's a short

Comment: Is it possible the system is designed for 120V power?

Comment: Could that be a transformer that can be re-configured for 120V or 230V, and someone has set it wrong?  It's common for transformers to have different primaries for different voltages.

Comment: What is the reference point for your measurements? This could be a split supply design.